# Apache .htaccess 403 a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an /uploads directory I wish to block from direct access. Of course I would put it outside the web root, but I'm really looking at a quick .htaccess fix.

Is there a way I can 403 or 404 a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. I put the following in  /uploads/.htaccess

```
<LIMIT GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from none
</LIMIT>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will cause a 403 Forbidden message to be sent by the server:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
```